# How to collect Django static files with the same name?

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

Three of my Django apps have static files with the same name `app1/static/css/mycss.css`, `app2/static/css/mycss.css`, `app3/static/css/mycss.css`. How do I collect them all to STATIC_ROOT since default behavior of DJango is to collect only the first one encountered among the same named static file?

Comment: Do you want all duplicates files to be merged into one `mycss.css`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the static files to be getting in each others way, give them their own name space by creating a suitable folder structure. Example

```
app1/static/css/app1/mycss.css
app2/static/css/app2/mycss.css
```

Alternatively if you want to combine all the CSS into one big CSS look into [django-compressor](https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor)